# RStudio crashes when running JDBC() function in the RJDBC package

Tags: r, rstudio, rjdbc

Whenever I try to make a JDBC object:

```
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", 
               classPath="~/ojdbc6.jar")
```

My RStudio immediately crashes with no warning with this popup

[image]

However, the code works perfectly in the terminal R environment outside of RStudio, so I am certain it is an RStudio issue.

OS: Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6

latest version of RStudio (1.1.456) and R (3.5.1).

JDK version 1.8.0_191

Using ojdbc6.jar

Comment: Up front: I don't use RStudio or a mac, and have shied away from `rJava` for a while ... but here's a thought: take a look at the (verbose) output of `Sys.getenv()` both in and out of RStudio to see if you can find distinct differences. Perhaps: `e <- Sys.getenv(); writeLines(paste(names(e), e, sep="|"), "file1");`, repeat in the other platform into `file2`, then on the terminal/command-linej type `diff file1 file2` (in the correct directory). It *might* give you an indication if an env var is "different-enough".

Comment: Might be related but Oracle for `odbc` package spins forever in RStudio. But placing `options(connectionObserver = NULL)` at the very top of script to avoid getting connection data for all its 500+ system tables, eliminated that problem for me.

Comment: @r2evans, I was able to do the diff between file1 and file2 and noticed that R terminal environment had JAVA_HOME set but RStudio did not. I was able to then fix the problem by including the JAVA_HOME path in my RStudio by creating the .Renviron file and setting it there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set JAVA_HOME in my terminal, but somehow it didn't "work" for RStudio.

So the fix was that I created an .Renviron file and put the following inside:

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home

That did the trick